# How to store big JSON hashes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm using the `elasticsearch-rails` gem and the `elasticsearch-model` gem and writing a query that happens to be really huge just because of the way the gem accepts queries.

The query itself isn't very long, but it's the filters that are very, very  long, and I need to pass variables in to filter out the results correctly. Here is an example:

```
def search_for(input, question_id, tag_id)
    query = {
        :query => {
            :filtered => {
                :query => {
                    :match => {
                        :content => input
                    }
                },
                :filter => {
                    :bool => {
                        :must => [
                            {
                                # another nested bool with should
                            },
                            {
                                # another nested bool with must for question_id
                            },
                            {
                                # another nested bool with must for tag_id
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    User.search(query) # provided by elasticsearch-model gem
end
```

For brevity's sake, I've omitted the other nested bools, but as you can imagine, this can get quite long quite fast.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to store this? I was thinking of a yml file, but it seems wrong especially because I need to pass in `question_id` and `tag_id`. Any other ideas?

If anyone is familiar with those gems and knows whether the gem's `search` method accepts other formats, I'd like to know that, too. Looks to me that it just wants something that can turn into a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a method is fine. I would separate the searching from the query:

```
def query_for(input, question_id, tag_id)
  query = {
    :query => {
    ...
end

search query_for(input, question_id, tag_id)
```

Also, I see that this search functionality is in the User model, but I wonder if it is belongs there. Would it make more sense to have a `Search` or `Query` model?

Comment: I didn't actually put the search on the model. That's something the gem does as a convenience, I guess.